# How to "untangle"/"unpivot" a comma-separated list into a flat table?

Tags: excel, powerquery, tableau-prep

I'll try to be short.

I have a table like that on the Left-hand-side (Firms is a unique list of IDs, and the second column is a comma-separated list of portfolio company IDs), and I need to untangle it into a table like on the right-hand-side so there's a straightforward flat relational table.

Any way to do that using Power Query, classic Excel, or Tableau Prep? Any method would work.

Thank you in advance!

Illustration "From-To"

[image: 1]

Comment: Is this a one-time thing you can do using helper columns, a one-time thing that can't be done with helpers, or something you want to be repeatable?

Answer (score 0):

In power query, you can split column by delimiter and you have an option to split into rows. You can do it all through the UI. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/split-a-column-of-text-power-query-5282d425-6dd0-46ca-95bf-8e0da9539662